# is this possible to use asymmetric encryption schemes as order preserving encryption

Tags: encryption

Are we able to use order preserving encryption in asymmetric schemes, is this work efficiently. is this secure at any one of the  situations

Answer (score 3):

No, because an adversary can pick an arbitrary plaintext, encrypt it using your public key, and then compute whether his plaintext is "less than" or "greater than" the plaintext corresponding to the ciphertext he wants to decrypt. He can do this intelligently several times to "home in" on your ciphertext's corresponding plaintext using binary search, allowing him to successfully decrypt any ciphertext using only the public key and your order relation in time $O(\log n)$ where $n$ is the size of the plaintext/ciphertext space, breaking the encryption scheme.

If this isn't what you meant, please add more detail to your question, including a list of the security properties desired.

Comment: thank you sir, if it is not possible to use asymmetric encryption scheme as order preserving one. How i implement modular order preserving encryption scheme for encrypting set of documents